# Write program to merge files and convert to .csv python?

Tags: python

I have written a program in python that does the following:

1. write an initial header in a new file
2. merge the files in the new file(ie append file to the new file, I want all my log files to be put together)
3. finally convert the space seperated file to csv.

What I do is mention the output directory where my file should be, and also a filelist,which contains the location of each file that should be merged, it looks like this:

```
/Users/ra/Documents/Dryad01/meow.log
/Users/ra/Documents/Dryad01/meow1.log
```

Then I do `python program.py path_to_list_file output_dir`

Here is my program :

```
import csv


def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("filelist", help="Format: Value File in each line")
    parser.add_argument("output_dir", help="output directory")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # write header
    fout = open(args.output_dir+"merged.txt","a")
    fout.write("timestamp         type       response_time")

    #from each file get the data and put it in fout/merge

    with open(args.filelist) as f:
        for file in f:
            file_read = open(file)
            for line in file_read:
                fout.write(line)

    fout.close()
    #now all file in filelist have been merged
    #next make them into csv files
    make_csv(args.output_dir+"merged.txt",args.output_dir+"merged_csv.csv")


def make_csv(file1,file2):
    with open(file1) as fin, open(file2, 'w') as fout:
        o=csv.writer(fout)
        for line in fin:
            o.writerow(line.split())
```

But for some reason I **get no error**, no warning,**but just no file**!
What do you think is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you maybe forget the following main pattern at the end of your source file?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If so, your `main()` function will never be called.

Comment: @LoveMeow: You're welcome. I've made that mistake myself a couple of times when I started with Python. Feel free to [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if that solved your problem :-)